# 'Gulp watch' event takes double the amount of time to compile less compared to normal 'gulp less' command

Tags: javascript, performance, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-less

I'm having issues with my Gulp 'watch' less function in that it is taking 2x longer to compile the less files compared with the individual less function.

When I use 'gulp less' it takes average of 9/10 seconds

```
[12:57:15] Starting 'less'...
[12:57:25] Finished 'less' after 9.96 s
```

However when I use 'gulp watch-less', then change a file to trigger the watch function it takes about double the time compared to 'gulp less'.

```
[13:03:43] Starting 'watch-less'...
[13:03:45] Finished 'watch-less' after 1.31 s
[13:03:48] Starting 'less'...
[13:04:06] Finished 'less' after 18 s
```

Below is my gulpfile.js which pulls in 'paths.json' as I've got 5 different themes (names are changed for this question) so the less file that is being used needs to be outputted into the relevant folder which is why I use the function 'updateDestFolder'.

The way the less is imported is that a change in the base theme should update the themes 2-5.

```
/*jslint node: true */
'use strict';

// Require the various plugins
var gulp     = require('gulp');
var watch    = require('gulp-watch');
var less     = require('gulp-less');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');

// Pull in External Paths JSON
var paths = require('./Config/paths.json');

// Determine output path depending on source path
function updateDestFolder(path) {
    var folder = '';

    if (path.indexOf(paths.themes.baseTheme) > -1) {
        folder = paths.themeDest.baseTheme;
    }
    else if (path.indexOf(paths.themes.theme2) > -1) {
        folder = paths.themeDest.theme2;
    }
    else if (path.indexOf(paths.themes.theme3) > -1) {
        folder = paths.themeDest.theme3;
    }
    else if (path.indexOf(paths.themes.theme4) > -1) {
        folder = paths.themeDest.theme4;
    }
    else if (path.indexOf(paths.themes.theme5) > -1) {
        folder = paths.themeDest.theme5;
    }

    return folder;
}

// Compile LESS
gulp.task('less', function() {
    var completeLessPaths = paths.less.src.concat(paths.less.ignore); // Merges both arrays
    var destFolder;

    return gulp.src(completeLessPaths)
        .pipe(plumber()) // Handle any errors with the plugins
        .pipe(less({
            strictUnits: true,
            compress: true // Minify the style
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(function (file) {
            destFolder = updateDestFolder(file.path);
            return destFolder + 'Styles/';
        }));
});

// Default tasks to run when 'gulp' is ran via command line
gulp.task('default', ['less', 'js', 'image']);

// Watch for changes to less source files, then fire the relevant function
gulp.task('watch-less', function () {
    gulp.watch(paths.less.src, ['less']);
});
```

Paths.json:

```
{
  "less" : {
    "src" : [
      "../Orchard.Web/Themes/Theme1Base/Styles/**/*.less",
      "../Orchard.Web/Themes/Theme2/Styles/**/*.less",
      "../Orchard.Web/Themes/Theme3/Styles/**/*.less",
      "../Orchard.Web/Themes/Theme4/Styles/**/*.less",
      "../Orchard.Web/Themes/Theme5/Styles/**/*.less"
    ],
    "ignore" : [
      "!../**/*.css",
      "!../**/bootstrap-overrides.less",
      "!../**/font-awesome.less",
      "!../**/Imports/**/*.less",
      "!../**/typography*.less",
      "!../**/*variables*.less"
    ]
  },
  "themes" : {
    "baseTheme": "Theme1Base",
    "theme2": "Theme2",
    "theme3": "Theme3",
    "theme4": "Theme4",
    "theme5": "Theme5",
  },
  "themeDest" : {
    "baseTheme" : "../Orchard.Web/Themes/Theme1Base/",
    "theme2" : "../Orchard.Web/Themes/Theme2/",
    "theme3" : "../Orchard.Web/Themes/Theme3/",
    "theme4": "../Orchard.Web/Themes/Theme4/",
    "theme5" : "../Orchard.Web/Themes/Theme5/",
  }
}
```

If anyone could suggest any improvements of determining the dest folder without needing to use the function I'd be grateful as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why it takes more time, but here's how you can determine dest folder better:

```
gulp.dst(function(file) { return file.split("/Styles")[0] + "/Styles/"; });
```